# type 'Rx<DateTime>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, frontend, flutter-getx

I called the showDatePicker function to be used on the registration screen. Since I wrote with getx, I used obs for instant display of the selected value, but I encountered the error as below.

"type 'Rx' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast"

```
class RegisterScreen extends GetWidget<RegisterController> {
  RegisterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = "/register_screen";
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs as DateTime;
  late BuildContext _context;
```

```
Obx(() => GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (() async {
                                var initialDate = DateTime.now();

                                _selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      initialDate: initialDate,
                                      firstDate: DateTime(1930),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                                    ) ??
                                    _selectedDate;
                                print(_selectedDate.toIso8601String());
                              }),
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      const Icon(
                                        FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
                                        size: 30,
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          DateFormat("EEE,MMM d")
                                              .format(_selectedDate),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs as DateTime;
```

to this:

```
var _selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs;
```

And use the value of `_selectedDate` like this everywhere:

```
_selectedDate.value
```

Check [this](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/state-management/reactive-state-manager/index/) to know more about [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).